# Get the short version of a song title from Deezer APIs

Tags: api, deezer

Deezer APIs (track and artist top method), when asking information about a track, sometime replies with a title very detailed, that could be something like

"Holiday (Album Version) (Album Version Faded Ending)"

Until a few days/weeks ago (I can't tell exactly the moment) the titles where much more synthetic (e.g. just "Holiday"). I see, however, that on the Deezer front-end the short version of the title is available, e.g. here:

```
http://www.deezer.com/track/17326261
```

you can see just "Stoned Immaculate" and you get the full title ("Stoned immaculate (LP version)") just if you browser the detail of the album.

Is it possible to get the short version of the title? I think that for most of the user this is more important than a long detailed version.

Answer (score 0):

It's not available yet in the Deezer API. It's in the roadmap, we'll keep everyone posted when it's there.